# How do I avoid using memory, or clear memory, when retrieving only the first item from an ArrayCollection?

Tags: php, symfony, memory, orm, doctrine

```
/**
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="DocumentData", mappedBy="document")
**/
private $records;
```

I currently have the above. I am using the below to retrieve the first record.

```
function getFirstRecord() {
  if (isset($this->records[0])) {
    return $this->records[0]->getData();
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

It's using far too much memory (3MB to 128MB after looping through 100 documents). I expect this is because on this line:

```
if (isset($this->records[0])) {
```

the entire $records ArrayCollection is loaded into memory, but I only need $records[0]. How can I avoid this or clear it from memory once I have the first record?

**EDIT:**

I now have:

```
  /**
  * @OneToMany(targetEntity="DocumentData", mappedBy="document", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
  **/
  private $records;
```

and

```
  function getFirstRecord() {
    $header;
    if ($this->records->containsKey(0)) {
      $header = $this->records->get(0);
      return $header->getData();
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, both the get and containsKey method still load the entire ArrayCollection. Is anyone able to spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you'll have to use a custom repository function for something like that. let us know when you need help to implement it, but give it a try first.

Comment: I guess you need this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Comment: @AndreyMischenko and LBA thanks heaps! This is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: @AndreyMischenko I've edited my answer with my attempt, but I can't seem to get it working using EXTRA_LAZY. I'm moving onto trying a custom repository function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution was to use a raw SQL query.

```
SELECT column FROM documentdata WHERE document_id = ". $docid ." LIMIT 1
```

I don't need a specific record just any record. I could not manage to get the expected output out of fetch="EXTRA_LAZY".